# How would I set up an equation to find the 3 separate amounts of money invested?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Scenario:

A total of $18,000 was divided and separated and to be invested in 3 different mutual funds, A, B, and C. Fund A promised to return 4% annual interest. Fund B, however lost 8% in annual interest. Fund C, returned only 2%

Overall, there was a net loss of $540 for the last year

Further, the original total was separated in such a way that fund B was greater than the sum of the two other funds by $2000

How much money was invested in funds A, B, and C?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**.  There will be three equations
$$A+B+C=\mathord?\ ,\qquad B-(A+C)=\mathord?\ ,\qquad 0.04A-0.08B+0.02C=\mathord?\ .$$
The three question marks are three amounts of money mentioned in the question (with a slight modification in one case).  See if you can finish the problem for yourself.